# Coordinates to work on any device Android

Tags: java, android, xml, coordinates

I want to make a multi-touchable `ImageView`. I made an `ontouchlistener` to get the coordinates `x` & `y` for the touch place and give it a reaction for every area. It works perfectly on `1080*1960` screen but for `720*1276` the coordinates change and the whole thing goes wrong . any ideas?

The `ImageView`

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78aeW.png)

Part of the code

```
                float x = motionEvent.getX();
                float y = motionEvent.getY();

            String message = String.format("Coordinates: (%.2f, %.2f)",x,y);
            //Toast.makeText(Study.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //To make the image clickable by Coordinates of touch

            if(x> 179 && x< 405  && y> 37 && y< 145 ){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"prep",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 405 && x < 550 && y >= 30 && y <135){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 570 && x < 684 &&y >= 49 && y < 190){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"2",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 675 && x < 822 &&y >= 143 && y < 315){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"3",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 757 && x < 870 &&y >= 290 && y < 447){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"4",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 346 && x < 686 &&y >= 760 && y < 845){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"1st",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 30 && x < 240 &&y >= 460 && y < 850){
                Toast.makeText(Study.this,"2nd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (x>= 240 && x < 755 &&y >= 150 && y < 750) {
            }
            return false;
```

Comment: you'd need to consider the size and pixel density of the display... relative instead of absolute coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following lines of code to get the pixel density, width in pixels, and height in pixels of the screen:

```
public static final double SCALE = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
public static final int WIDTH = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
public static final int HEIGHT = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

Now use these constants in your if statements as follows:

```
if((x > WIDTH / 2 - SCALE * 50) && (x < WIDTH / 2 + SCALE * 50)  && (Y > HEIGHT/ 2 - SCALE * 50) && (Y < HEIGHT/ 2 + SCALE * 50)){ 
    Toast.makeText(Study.this,"prep",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The code above will show the toast if the user were to touch a square of width 100, height 100, and centered in the screen.

The size and relative position of that square will be the same across all devices.

Comment: for the first lines of code AS give me this error Error:(32, 40) error: cannot find symbol variable Resources

Comment: @MohamedGamal Can you show me the entire class which you put the code in? It would help me better understand the problem.

Comment: @MohamedGamal Please try getApplicationContext: `public static final double SCALE = getApplicationContext().Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
public static final int WIDTH = getApplicationContext().Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
public static final int HEIGHT = getApplicationContext().Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;`

Comment: @MohamedGamal sorry but I do not know how to help you further.

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway :) and btw I fixed it using this code

Comment: <code>
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        final int width = size.x;
        final int height = size.y;

float x = motionEvent.getX();
float y = motionEvent.getY();

//as I recorded coords from 1080*1770 screen
 if(x> 179*width/1080 && x< 405*width/1080  && y> 37*height/1770 && y< 145*height/1770){//prep
                    year = 0;
                    yearImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bprep);
                }<code>